# Bragg-reflection

Tags: x-ray-crystallography, braggs-law

I'm currently trying to prove Planck's constant, with the use of a NaCl-kristal and X-ray.
But when I use the formula $n\lambda=2dsin\theta$, with $n=1,\ \lambda = hc/E,\ E=qU,\ U=35kV,\ \theta = 7.3$ it gives a $d$ half the literary value of around $141\ pm$ instead of $282\ pm$. Why do I get half, and what did I do wrong?

Comment: are you sure it is $2d\sin\vartheta$ not $d\sin\vartheta$?